# Why do I get warning "dead code"?

Tags: java, dead-code

```
public class DeadCodeInLuna {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String string;
        for (string = in.readLine(); !string.equals(""); string=in.readLine()) {
            if(string == null) { 
               System.out.println("null while reading response!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are performing null check after comparing vlaue so object can't be null after that try to change 
            if(string == null) { for (string = in.readLine(); !string.equals(""); string=in.readLine()) {

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `string` can never be `null` if `!string.equals("")` evaluates to `true`.

In other words, when `!string.equals("")` is `true`, `string` is guaranteed to be not `null` otherwise a `NullPointerException` would have occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Because at that point of the code, `string` cannot be null. If it came out `null` from the `in.readLine()`, you'd get a `NullPointerException` at the condition check of the `for`.

Change it to

```
    for(string=in.readLine();!"".equals(string);string=in.readLine())
        if(string==null) System.out.println("null while reading response!");
    }
```

where the `equals` will work regardless of whether or not `string` is null, and you'll see the warning go away.

Answer (score 0):

In your condition you avoid to `string == null`

```
for (string = in.readLine(); !string.equals(""); string=in.readLine()) {
//                           ^--------> here!!!
```

So `if(string == null)` is redundant and will never be true